# using pip freeze from embedded python with subprocess gives 120 return code

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to manage an external virtual python environment from an embedded python 3.6. When I create a virtual environment and request the package list with `pip.exe freeze` with subprocess.run with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` I get a return code 120, the output seems correct though.

This does not happen when I use the system python which is also 3.6. Working example:

```
import subprocess

# Define target dir: 
target_dir = "C:/test/venv"
# Create venv:
command = f"C:/MSC.Software/Adams/2020/python/win64/python.exe -m venv {target_dir}"
subprocess.run(command,check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Get package list:
command = f"{target_dir}/Scripts/pip.exe freeze"
response = subprocess.run(command,check=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response.decode()
```

I don't understand where this error comes from, I solved it now with `check=False`.

Comment: Is it correct that it is `pip.ex`?

Comment: No that is not correct, that's a typo that's only here but not in my own code. Sorry!

Comment: first check what you get with `f"{target_dir}/Scripts/pip.exe freeze"` and try it in console

Comment: when you run `subprocess` without `shell=True` then you should use list `["f"{target_dir}/Scripts/pip.exe", "freeze"]` and `["C:/MSC.Software/Adams/2020/python/win64/python.exe", "-m", "venv", target_dir]`

Comment: Just to clarify, I tried running the commands in the terminal and there it runs fine. The problem is really in the embedded python which has a problem with the pipe it seems.